# BBB - WLAN USB Adapter configuration problems

Tags: linux, debian, driver, beagleboneblack, beagleboard

yesterday i baught a new WLAN Nano USB Adapter (LogiLink/WL0084E/Should be supported by Linux). Now i have tried to get it running with my BBB which is running on Debian Wheezy. 
First i pluged the WLAN USB Adapter in and i got following Result using `lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:8179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
```

I have googled for the ID `0bda:8179` and found following Website: https://wiki.debian.org/rtl819x wich told me to install `firmware-realtek` by using `sudo apt-get install firmware-realtek`. After that i should restart by  System `shutdown -h now` and power on again (I know a `reboot` will do the same).
But the WLAN Adapter was not recoginzed as wlan0 - if i type in `ip a` i got following result:

```
1:  lo:     ...
2:  eth0:   ...
3:  usb0:   ...
```

The Website mentioned above told me that i need the module `r8188eu` - But on `lsmod` i got following output:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
g_multi                50407  2
libcomposite           15028  1 g_multi
omap_rng                4062  0
mt7601Usta            458758  0
```

So i tought `mt7601Usta` can may be the right one and i typed in `modinfo mt7601Usta`

```
filename:       /lib/modules/3.8.13-bone79/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/mt7601Usta.ko
version:        3.0.0.3
description:    RT2870 Wireless Lan Linux Driver
```

But may this driver doesnt Support the WL0084E (Supported by Linux!).

> What should i do? 
>   Why do i not have the wlan0 interface? 
>   How can i fix this Problem?

If you need more information, told me commands to execute ;)
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest 8188 driver from realteks website, extract and run install.sh 
http://www.realtek.com/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&ProdID=274&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true

If that doesn't work either just give up with trying to get Wheezy to support it and just hope it works automatically in a newer distro/kernel